Access Denied Error when Uploading Files from VM to Cloud Storage
I’m trying to upload files from a VM instance to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using the gcloud storage cp command. I’ve attached a service account to the VM with Storage Admin access, but I’m encountering an access denied error.
gcloud storage cp temp_files/test.txt gs://test-us-east/test.txt
Error message:
Copying file://temp_files/test.txt to gs://test-us-east/test.txt
ERROR: User [vm-instances-sa@gcpplatform.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access b instance [test-us-east] (or it may not exist): Access denied.
Completed files 0/1 | 0B

I’ve verified that the service account has the necessary permissions to create objects in the bucket using the Policy Analyzer. Despite temporarily granting Owner access, the issue persists.
I also checked the permissions tab under my bucket, and it shows my service account with storage admin permissions. Additionally, I reviewed the access scope for my VM, and it allows access to all APIs.

So removing all permissions from the service account and granting only storage admin access, along with full API access for Cloud Scope, ultimately worked. I stopped the current VM and restarted it, and now the gcloud cp command is functioning properly.

As the error you have given doesn’t have enough information to debug this issue, check the logs for any specific error or codes for further debugging. Meanwhile try this troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue:

Check if IAM Service Account Credentials API and Google Cloud Storage API is enabled.

Before editing an instance  to allow access to all APIs you need to stop the instance, edit, save your changes and restart your virtual machine.

You can try the 'gcloud auth login' command to authenticate with an account which has editor or ownership permissions to the project. Then upload the files to the Cloud Storage.

Once you are inside the terminal of your virtual machine enter "gcloud init" and set up your service account using the default service account choosing option 1 or option 2 to log in with a new account. Once logged in, try uploading your file with the gsutil command, which might look like this: gsutil cp empty.file gs://ctrain01/.

Make sure the bucket which you are trying to copy exists in your project.


Check this doc for more information.

I have already tried all of these solutions. The service account has all the API access from the scope. When I run gcloud auth list, the correct service account shows as logged in, but I still encounter the same error when using gsutil.

then it might be an issue can you create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue. If you have paid support try create an issue

So removing all permissions from the service account and granting only storage admin access, along with full API access for Cloud Scope, ultimately worked. I stopped the current VM and restarted it, and now the gcloud cp command is functioning properly.

Thank you, this helped pointing me the right direction. Though removing old conf solved my issue rm -r .config/gcloud/
f* you Google
